# tar compress only if source files updated

Tags: tar, compression

I am implementing a process in which a tar.gz file is created that compresses various files needed from the process. When this compression is done I don't want it to be compressed again, or crush the new file if none of the source files have changed (not even the modification date of the resulting tar.gz).

It is assumed that the compressed tar.gz file is not removed once compressed.

Example:

```
tar -czvf booktypes.tar.gz \
        classics \
        adventure \
        history \
        crime \
        horror \
        fantasy
```

If any of the book types have changed something in their archive, then update the tar, otherwise don't update the tar, not even its modification date.

Of course I could make a sh script that does this check. But my question is whether to perform this check **using only the tar command**.

I mean, does tar command have something built-in like this?

Comment: Did you test the option `--listed-incremental=FILE` ? See details in `man tar`.

Comment: The `-d` (diff) and `-u` (update) options should solve your issue. Both are well documented.

Comment: you can create file after first tar and use option `-N`. And then update the tar